# Eclipse not giving an this errors or warnings: 'Tomcat: multiple contexts path of..' and pom.xml file

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse Java EE 2018-09(4.9.0) is working on Ubuntu 18.04. The problem is, it is not working properly. I got this issues:

- Tomcat server had an "Multiple contexts have path of ..." error, but Eclipse didn't warn me.
- In pom.xml file had an error about "web xml missing ...", but again, Eclipse didn't warn me.

I saw this errors from tutorials. Why is this happening? Is it about configuration or something?

I tried cleaning project, update maven project, building again, but still getting this errors.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which version eclipse you are using. But you can try this way.

```
Window-->Preferences-->General-->Editor-->Text Editors-->Annotations-->Error
```

and there are three checkboxs. Check them.

Comment: all annotations already working, but this time i got that tomcat error. maybe it was about cache or something. thanks